# Access firestore from non-google server? (do i just upload the service account json?)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore as my db, but django as my web framework. I want to host my website using AWS, and i suppose in order to do that, i can just upload the service account json to the project folder on my AWS instance. and have the env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS point to the path of the service account file?

Comment: Check out [how to initialize the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk), if you get to choose this SDK, as an example for more information. I hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is one way to do what you want. Depending on the SDK you're using, you could also provide the credentials as an argument to whatever code initializes the SDK.